# Accept HashMap<String, SomePyClass> as function argument in pyo3

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm trying to get a pyfunction to work in pyo3 that accepts a `HashMap<String, SomePyClass>` but I get "the trait `pyo3::FromPyObject<'_>` is not implemented for `HashMap<String, Bar>`". From what I understand, structs attributed with `#[pyclass]` do implement `FromPyObject` [edit: this seems to be incorrect], as does `String`, as does `HashMap<K, V>` as long as `K` and `V` implement `FromPyObject`. So what am I doing wrong and how can I get it to work? This is using pyo3 0.21.0-beta.0.

```rust
#[pyclass]
struct Bar;

#[pyfunction]
fn example(foo: HashMap<String, Bar>) {}
```

Comment: "structs attributed with #[pyclass] do implement FromPyObject" - I wasn't able to find this in the docs, could you point me on the source you're referring to?

Comment: you're right, I think that's incorrect.

So is it not possible to get a hashmap like that from the python side?

Comment: Can't check it myself right now, but what if you use `HashMap<String, Py<Bar>>`, i.e. store not the class itself, but the Python-managed reference to it? It should have the necessary implementation, if I read the docs correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take [`PyRef<Class>`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/pycell/struct.PyRef.html) or [`PyRefMut<Class>`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/pycell/struct.PyRefMut.html):

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn example(foo: HashMap<String, PyRef<'_, Bar>>) {}
```